# Re-format NSString representing a date

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, string-formatting

How would I convert @"20090302" to @"2009/03/02" or to @"02/03/2009"?

I found the solution and this is the update

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMDD"];



NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:yourinoutstring];


[formatter setDateFormat:@"DD/MM/YYYY"];

NSString *outDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: Answered duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate

Comment: I need the output to be nsstring too

Comment: Then convert `NSString -> NSDate -> NSString`. What are you using the date for?

Comment: I just want to formate the nsstring @"20100304" to @"04/02/2010" for displaying purpose

Comment: I disagree that the linked question also answers this one. Therefore, I have edited this question (particularly the title) to clarify it and provided an answer.

Answer (score 7):

You will want to use an [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this purpose.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"YourDateInputFormat"];
```

Where you can figure out what `@"YourDateInputFormat"` should be by reading the Data Formatting Guide, [Date Formatters chapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000029i). You get an `NSDate` from that:

```
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:yourString];
```

Then change the formatter's format to give the output you want:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YourDateOutputFormat];
```

Then you can convert that date and get the string you want:

```
NSString *outString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: thanks your answer helped me , but it's outdated code I use ios 4.2

Comment: `-initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage:` is only for pre-10.4 formatter behavior.  You need to use `-init` and `-setDateFormat:` separately.

Comment: @Dave: thanks for pointing that out. Sorry, Ali. I've edited my answer.