# convert NSString to NSDate

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSString to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate)

Hi I want to convert the string "`OCT 1, 2011 18:30`" into `NSDate` format `2011-05-13 19:00:00 +0800.`
I have tried with the many formatters but what I am getting is a null value each time. 
Can any body help me on this?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so we can identify where you may have gone wrong?

Comment: NSDate does not have a "format". Do you mean you want to convert a string of a date in one format to a string of the same date in another format?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate

Comment: Duplicate of that question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code that will help you because I run successfully.

```
    NSString *dateStr = @"OCT 1, 2011 18:30";
    NSDateFormatter *dtF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dtF setDateFormat:@"LLL d, yyyy HH:mm"];
    NSDate *d = [dtF dateFromString:dateStr];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatStr = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatStr setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *st = (NSDate *)[dateFormatStr stringFromDate:d];   
    NSLog(@"%@",st);
```

Comment: Thanks form my side.. i am also searching this.. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
NSDateFormatter *datefor = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
     [datefor setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"];
     NSDate *date = [datefor dateFromString:@"OCT 1, 2011 18:30"];
    [datefor setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"]; 
     NSString *str=  [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[datefor stringFromDate:date]];
     NSDate *date_fianl = [datefor dateFromString:str];
      [str release];
     NSLog(@"%@",date_fianl);//it will print 2011-10-01 01:00:00 +0000
```