# How can I Convert a NSString to a valid NSDate (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdate

I'm passing a string from javascript to Objective-C in the form of "2012-02-17 14:21:30 +0000". 
My code is as follows:

```
NSString *firingDate = [_parameters objectForKey:@"fire"];
NSDate *notificationDate = [NSDate dateWithString:firingDate];
```

The issue is that I ended up reading the OS X reference instead of the iOS docs (doh!) so this throws a warning as dateWithString isn't present in iOS. In theory I suppose that this shouldn't work at all but it does, albeit with that warning.

What is the Correct way to convert the string to a NSDate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString to NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";
NSDate *notificationDate = [formatter dateFromString:firingDate];
```

Comment: I think the date format should be "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" (thats what worked for me)

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is to use `NSDateFormatter` as a factory to create dates from strings (and vice versa).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSString *firingDate = [_parameters objectForKey:@"fire"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *notificationDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:firingDate];
```

Check out the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html) for parsing dates from multiple regions.

Don't forget to release your formatter when finished.