# String to NSDate format conversion

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I want to convert following string into NSDate format

2012-04-29T08:20:04Z

Please help me. How I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string
{
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormat setLocale:locale];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];

NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:string];  
if(!date1) date1= [NSDate date];
[dateFormat release];
[locale release];

return date1;
}
```

Tell me if it helps!!!

Comment: It converts into date but it gives wrong output like               String: 2012-04-25T16:05:24Z                                        o/p after convert is: 2012-05-02 12:16:33 +0000

Comment: Which locale u wanna use? And also adjust ur timezone as well.

Comment: How I can adjust? I didn't get Please help me

Comment: Read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Answer (score 0):

here's a possible same question and some solution :

[NSString to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate)

you can make your own format to fit your request..

hope this helps ..