# iPhone: how to convert nsstring to nsdate

Tags: nsstring, nsdate

I want to this string to nsdate

"2012-12-25T18:58:57.649Z"

I Know how to convert nsstring to nsdate but i am unable to find the proper format. I set following format but it does not work. Please suggest

```
[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: You forgot add ms to formatter

Comment: i used this one [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.msZ"]; and this one [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ms"]; . Both format does not works

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString to NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromISO8601:(NSString *)str{
   if(![str isKindOfClass:NSString.class]){
      return nil;
   }

   static NSDateFormatter* sISO8601 = nil;

   if (!sISO8601) {
      sISO8601 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
      [sISO8601 setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
      [sISO8601 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S"];
      [sISO8601 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
  }
  if ([str hasSuffix:@"Z"]) {
      str = [str substringToIndex:(str.length-1)];
  }

  NSDate *d = [sISO8601 dateFromString:str];
  return d;
 }
```