# DateFormatter keep returning null

Tags: objective-c

I have a date i take from twitter :

```
  NSString *date=[twt objectForKey:@"created_at"];
  NSLog(@"%@",date);
  NSDateFormatter *df = [ [NSDateFormatter alloc] init]  ;
  [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
  NSDate *newdate = [df dateFromString:date];
  NSLog(@"new: %@",newdate); //null
```

the date is : `Thu Jun 12 20:56:53 +0000 2014` and i get null on the new date .
What am i missing ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString to NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the date formatter for that format (`Thu Jun 12 20:56:53 +0000 2014`) would be this:

## "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"

rather than this `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"`.

Answer (score 1):

The date formatting string you've shared sure does't look like it matches the date you're getting from Twitter. The docs for `dateFromString` state...

> A date representation of string interpreted using the receiver’s
>   current settings. If dateFromString: can not parse the string, returns
>   nil.

Read up!

http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns