# NSDate To and From NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

It is too much confusing and  i have pasted my code below.

I have a eopoc time.

// Function that converts eopc to NSString

```
NSString * ConvertEpocToDateStr(NSString *epoc)
{

    NSString *res;

    NSTimeInterval sec = [epoc doubleValue]/1000.0;

    NSDate *eDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:sec];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];


    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd hh:mm a"];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"IST"];
    NSLog (@" Time in your Zone is %@ ", [[dateFormatter timeZone] description]);
    res = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:eDate];

    return res;
}
```

// From NSString to back NSDate.

```
NSDate * backToDate (NSString * dInStr )
{
    NSDateFormatter *dFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd hh:mm a"];
    dFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"IST"];

    NSDate *FromString = [dFormatter dateFromString:dInStr];
    return dFromString;

}
```

And, I tried to print below .

epoc ->   1397600251077

ConvertEpocToDateStr -> 04/16 03:47 am
  backToDate           -> 2000-04-15 22:17:00 +0000

Both should be same right? I am not sure where/what i am missing?

Comment: Dateformater from string should be the same format as your string. If your string with date different than date formatter you will get nil

Comment: i have used same data format only "MM/dd hh:mm a"

Comment: @Whoami you need 2 formatters bro

Comment: Thanks for reply. Would you mind showing little more light on it ;)

Comment: There are literally thousands of examples of how to do this conversion on SO.  Your NSLog is wrong since it's logging the description of the date formatter, not the date.  Otherwise what you have appears to be correct, converting from Unix epoch to string time.

Comment: @meda -- He does not need two formatters.

Comment: You are getting a date in 2000 going backwards because the string time does not contain the year.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString to NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate)

Comment: Do note that you should pay attention to [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6613110/581994);

Comment: @HotLicks why dont you post an answer, obviously your thought dont fit in the comments lol

Comment: @meda - It's been answered already.  The code is working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you get the same dates. IST is 5.30 h ahead of GMT+0.
Since you drop out year in your direct formatter and use the date time string without the year
by default it is set to 2000.

Evidently, `2000-04-15 22:17:00 +0000` is the same as `2000-04-16 03:47:00 +0530`.